# Using SUM and Group By in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a SQL query which produces an output that I want. But I have difficulty adapting it to a LINQ query.

My normal SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT ORDNO,CURR,SUM(AMOUNT) as SUMMEDAMT
FROM YTDTRNS
GROUP BY ORDNO,CURR
```

I have written a Class like this for my LINQ query:

```
public class SpecialClass
{ 
    public string ORDNO { get; set; }
    public string CURR { get; set; }
    public double SUMMEDAMT { get; set; }
}
```

For my LINQ Query I have so far been able to do this:

```
var result = db.YTDTRNS.GroupBy(y => new
        {
            y.ORDNO,
            y.CURR

        }
        ).Select(z => new SpecialClass
        {
            ORDNO = z.Key.ORDNO,
            CURR = z.Key.CURR

        }
        );
```

I tried to write the LINQ query with the SUM function like this:

```
 var result = db.YTDTRNS.GroupBy(y => new
        {
            y.ORDNO,
            y.CURR

        }
        ).Select(z => new SpecialClass
        {
            ORDNO = z.Key.ORDNO,
            CURR = z.Key.CURR,
            SUMMEDAMT = z.Sum(a => a.AMOUNT)

        }
        );
```

The above seems to be incorrect. When I make an AJAX request to function written earlier, I get the correct result set.

Once I include "SUM" into that function, when I make an AJAX request to that function, I received an internal server error.

This was the error message shown ajax error() function:

"ExceptionMessage":"The cast to value type 'System.Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.",
"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"

Comment: "I know that the above is incorrect" - how do you know that? Do you get a compile error? A runtime error? Do you get 0 when you expect to get a value? Something else? At a glance that looks fine to me but if you gave me an error message I could probably do a much better job of working out what is going wrong...

Comment: can you check if there is any typecast exception ? try to wrap it in try and check what causes the internal server error.

Comment: I made an AJAX request to that function. When it didn't include 'SUM', it returned the result set properly, once I modify that function, the AJAX request returned an internal server error...

Comment: Wrap your code in a try/catch exception and let it return the exception. We need to be sure what is the error

Comment: the ajax error shown this: "ExceptionMessage":"The cast to value type 'System.Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.", "ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"

Comment: @jinchengteo check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,

after reading your update, I guess probably you are using LINQ to Entities, which does not support `Sum(expression)`

You can try this:

```
SUMMEDAMT = z.Select(a => a.AMOUNT).Sum()
```

But i still suggest you wrap your code in try/catch and return the exception so it will return a clearer message instead of internal server error

**EDIT:**
Your class should be same as your db, so you should declare like this:

```
public double? SUMMEDAMT { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer below code to use sum in linq queries.

Example:

Lets have players. Each player belongs to a team and have a score. Team total score is sum of score of all players in the team.

```
var players = new List<Player> {
    new Player { Name = "Alex", Team = "A", Score = 10 },
    new Player { Name = "Anna", Team = "A", Score = 20 },
    new Player { Name = "Luke", Team = "L", Score = 60 },
    new Player { Name = "Lucy", Team = "L", Score = 40 },
};

var teamTotalScores =
    from player in players
    group player by player.Team into playerGroup
    select new
    {
        Team = playerGroup.Key,
        TotalScore = playerGroup.Sum(x => x.Score),
    };
```

Comment: This looks like the same code but using query syntax instead of method syntax - you should probably explain with reference to the user's code what they need to do to get their code working. ie if you are going to paste a working example do so with the user's variables and classes.